# Comparing version numbers in cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, versioning, cassandra-3.0

I have a C* table with different config values that are relevant only for certain versions of the application - versions between [min_version, max_version).

```
config_name     | min_version | max_version 
defaultConfig1  | 1.0.0       | 1.2.3 
defaultConfig2  | 10.0.1      | 11.1.2 
defaultConfig3  | 4.1.2       | 5.0.0
defaultConfig4  | 5.3.4       | 6.1.2
```

Version 1.1.1 would fall into the [1.0.0, 1.2.3) interval, therefore we should return defaultConfig1.

Does Cassandra support writing a query that picks an entry from a table that has a version parameter in a certain interval [min_version, max_version)? (we should compare version numbers, not strings)

I know this can be achieved in Java by converting version numbers to version objects and comparing the version objects. I'm wondering if the same thing can be directly achieved in Cassandra?

Answer (score 0):

The CQL grammar mostly supports the equality operator, with very limited support for range queries for certain data types.

It might be possible to model your data to support your queries. For example, break up `min_version` into 3 columns:

- `major_version`
- `minor_version`
- `patch_version`

so you can perform range queries with a predicate like:

```
... WHERE major_version = ? AND minor_version < ?
```

However, complex queries like your use case would be better served by indexing your data with software like Elasticsearch or Apache Lucene/Solr so you can perform complex searches against the data in Cassandra. Cheers!